# Nested quotations in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, nested, mouseover, quotations

I'm playing around with some bbcode for my forum, and I stumbled upon a problem concerning multiple nested quotations.
I'm trying to implement an image tooltip on mouseover.

```
<a href="javascript:void;" onmouseover="tooltip.show(\'<img src=\1.jpg>\', 200);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">\1</a>',
```

(The **\1** is the value which the user inputs between the [img][/img] tags.)

As you can see, I don't have quotes around my img src. What is the right syntax to indicate this, with nested quotations?
I've tried to use backslashes ( \\" etc.) but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: May be you need to use `&quot;`. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

All your quotation (and many other) problems will go away once you stop adding event listeners inline in HTML.

HTML is to represent textual and multimedia data, it shouldn't contain inline CSS and JavaScript.

As the first step, you could reorganize your code so that all JavaScript is in separate files.

In HTML:

```
<a class="bbcode-link" data-src="\1">\1</a>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

In `script.js`:

```
function showTooltip(e) {
    var filename = e.target.getAttribute('data-src')
    return tooltip.show('<img src="' + filename + '.jpg" />', 200)
}

function hideTooltip() {
    return tooltip.hide()
}

[].forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('a.bbcode-link'),
    function (link) {
        link.addEventListener('mouseover', showTooltip, false)
        link.addEventListener('mouseout', hideTooltip, false)
    }
)
```

Also I hope you sanitize the user input before inserting it into HTML.

**Reference links:**

- [`element.addEventListener` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE9+)
- [`element.attachEvent` at
  MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (IE6-8)

Comment: @Felix Kling, thanks! Perhaps a micro-library for DOM events (like [Bean](https://github.com/fat/bean)) could make browser abstraction easier.

Comment: Maybe I should also explain why: Firefox expects three parameters passed to `addEventListener` (last one defining whether the handler is fired in the capture or bubble phase) and this function does not exist in IE8 and below. It's not difficult to create an extra function to make the distinction for W3C and IE. Or if the code is really simple, I would just assign the event handlers to the properties: `link.onmouseover = function(){...}` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
<a href="javascript:void;" 
onmouseover="tooltip.show('<img src=&quot;\1.jpg&quot;>', 200);"
onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">\1</a>',
```

Carefully check how I have used `&quot;` to prevent the browser from parsing the quotation to a attribute value delimiter. Also you dont have to escape `'` character inside an attribute value.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgtFT/1/)